# I want to skip tests with the @ignore tag in spec flow

Tags: selenium, resharper, specflow

I am running my spec flow feature files with the help of resharper and certain feature files have been ignored for later use with @ignore tag. What happens is that chromedriver opens these tests, realizes that they are ignored and stop the test. As I run the tests from a folder, it takes upto 5 mins for every folder that contain these ignored tests. Is there a way to prevent the test runner,runnning these ignored tests so that I can save some time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on where you are starting chromedriver from. If you are starting the driver in a `[BeforeScenario]` step then yes. Its as simple as this:

```
if(!ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("ignore")){
    //start chromedriver
}
```

in this way you can check to make sure if the current scenario should be ignored or not and avoid starting chromedriver if it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks perfect but looks like the webdriver fires from a [BeforeFeature] step.... so this is not working.

Comment: Actually made it work!! I just changed the [BeforeFreature] tag to [BeforeScenario] and bam! it worked. The testrunner builds the test and doesn't open the chromedriver and within the blink of an eye, there is a message in the unit test session window that the tests have been ignored. Thanks heaps.

Comment: You also need to check FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Tags for ignore if you're going to use @ignore on an entire feature file. But in either case BeforeScenario won't get run if the scenario or feature is ignored with the ignore tag